# Arithmetic with columns in different tables in mysql [optmization]

Tags: mysql

In the following query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT nick FROM nicks n WHERE n.pid=p.id LIMIT 1 ORDER BY id DESC) as nick
  , (
          (
             ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kills k WHERE k.pid = p.id ) 
             + 
             ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votos v WHERE v.pid = p.id )
           ) 
          - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deaths d WHERE d.pid = p.id )
  ) as score
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kills k WHERE k.pid = p.id ) as kills
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deaths d WHERE d.pid = p.id ) as deaths
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headshots h WHERE h.pid = p.id ) as headshots
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votos v WHERE v.pid = p.id ) as reputation
FROM  players p
WHERE p.uuid='STEAM_x:x:xxxxxx'
GROUP BY kills
```

This query works fine... but i think there exists a better way to do this.
Can anyone help me optimize this query?

[image]

Comment: Your query, as written, should return a syntax error because of the first subquery.  Do all the tables have indexes on `pid`?  Although you could probably do more optimization, that will probably result in fast-enough performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, nop... The query works.. but no have indexes on pid... Add a index in all tables is all i can do to improve performance? i am suprised with myself.. because sql is not my area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat better way to write the query:

```
SELECT p.*, (kills + reputation - deaths) as score
FROM (SELECT (SELECT nick FROM nicks n WHERE n.pid = p.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
             ) as nick,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kills k WHERE k.pid = p.id ) as kills,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deaths d WHERE d.pid = p.id ) as deaths,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM headshots h WHERE h.pid = p.id ) as headshots,
             (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votos v WHERE v.pid = p.id ) as reputation
      FROM players p
      WHERE p.uuid = 'STEAM_x:x:xxxxxx'
     ) p
GROUP BY kills;
```

Note:  I don't understand what the `GROUP BY` is doing.  You are only aggregating by one column, so the rest of the columns have *indeterminate* values.  Perhaps you intend `ORDER BY`.

I am guessing that the overhead for materializing the subquery before the `group by` is slightly less than the additional subqueries.  But your version may have very comparable performance.

For either version, you want the following indexes:

- `players(uuid)`
- `kills(pid)`
- `deaths(pid)`
- `headshots(pid)`
- `votos(pid)`